# How to properly mock the file reader using Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I'm trying to mock a file reader, and I have a function that accepts a callback, but during the test, the line where the callback is called is not covered. How can this be solved?

function:

```
const testFunction = (uint8arr, callback) => {
  const bb = new Blob([uint8arr]);
  const f = new FileReader();
  f.onload = function (e) {
    callback(e.target.result);
  };

  f.readAsText(bb);
};

module.exports = { testFunction };
```

test:

```
const { testFunction } = require("./index");

class FileReaderMock {
  DONE = FileReader.DONE;
  EMPTY = FileReader.EMPTY;
  LOADING = FileReader.LOADING;
  readyState = 0;
  error = null;
  result = null;
  abort = jest.fn();
  addEventListener = jest.fn();
  dispatchEvent = jest.fn();
  onabort = jest.fn();
  onerror = jest.fn();
  onload = jest.fn();
  onloadend = jest.fn();
  onloadprogress = jest.fn();
  onloadstart = jest.fn();
  onprogress = jest.fn();
  readAsArrayBuffer = jest.fn();
  readAsBinaryString = jest.fn();
  readAsDataURL = jest.fn();
  readAsText = jest.fn();
  removeEventListener = jest.fn();
}

const mockCallback = jest.fn();

describe("testFunction", () => {
  const fileReader = new FileReaderMock();

  jest.spyOn(window, "FileReader").mockImplementation(() => fileReader);

  it("should be called mockCallback and readAsText with the blob value", () => {
    const uintArray = new Uint8Array();
    testFunction(uintArray, mockCallback);

    // expect(mockCallback).toHaveBeenCalled();
    // expect(fileReader.readAsText).toHaveBeenCalledWith(new Blob([uintArray]));
  });
});
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jest-test-forked-ecejb?file=/index.test.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the getter and setter of the `Object.defineProperty()` method to intercept the assignment operation of the `onload` function, so you can get the `onload` function to test it as usual.

E.g.

`index.js`:

```js
const testFunction = (uint8arr, callback) => {
  const bb = new Blob([uint8arr]);
  const f = new FileReader();
  f.onload = function (e) {
    callback(e.target.result);
  };

  f.readAsText(bb);
};

module.exports = { testFunction };
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const { testFunction } = require('./index');

describe('testFunction', () => {
  it('should be called mockCallback and readAsText with the blob value', () => {
    const mockCallback = jest.fn();
    const fileReader = {
      readAsText: jest.fn(),
    };
    let onloadRef;
    Object.defineProperty(fileReader, 'onload', {
      get() {
        return this._onload;
      },
      set(onload) {
        onloadRef = onload;
        this._onload = onload;
      },
    });
    jest.spyOn(window, 'FileReader').mockImplementation(() => fileReader);
    const uintArray = new Uint8Array();
    testFunction(uintArray, mockCallback);

    // onload test
    const event = { target: { result: 'teresa teng' } };
    onloadRef(event);
    expect(mockCallback).toBeCalledWith('teresa teng');
    expect(fileReader.readAsText).toBeCalledWith(new Blob([uintArray]));
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/66964346/index.test.js (7.479 s)
  testFunction
    ✓ should be called mockCallback and readAsText with the blob value (4 ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.js |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        8.575 s, estimated 9 s
```